# IE 9, minimum privacy and security settings, always get 3rd party cookies disabled message

Tags: bug, status-norepro, unanswered-questions, stack-exchange-openid

When attempting to log in using StackExchange, I am told I am not accepting third party cookies. I am using IE 9 and I have set security and privacy settings to absolute minimum, as well as added exceptions to all stackexchange.com.
I have fw/av up (Trend Micro) but no proxy. I have added an exception for stackexchange.com.

**Is there a *different domain* I should add?**

(The 's' in cookie[s] is no longer missing. Much more professional!)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled" When trying to login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103007/third-party-cookies-appear-to-be-disabled-when-trying-to-login)

Comment: Hrm... stackauth maybe? Not a dupe, but see [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't reproduce this. Do you have any other anti-virus, firewall, or proxy software running that would interfere?

With out of box default IE9 settings, everything should "just work".

Comment: I do have fw/av up, but have added an exception for stackexchange.com. Is there a different domain I should add?

Comment: I've further experimented with Trend Micro and essentially disabled most of its security features as well. I've also overriden the IE settings to always accept third party cookies... no luck! Any suggestions?

Comment: I will accept that this should work out of the box, as it seems to for most peeps. My particular problem, however, remains unresolved. This q continues to get views... perhaps people with a similar problem?

Comment: Please fix this, @Telis is right, I tried to create a StackExchange ID, and get the stupid 'Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled' which is patently not true.

Comment: @lance still no repro; I just fired up IE9 and created a new openid.stackexchange.com account and logged in to pm, here, as this user: http://pm.stackexchange.com/users/1825/user1825

Comment: Same issue here on Chrome and IE9 and with different Windows user accounts.

Comment: @luke check for any proxies, firewalls, or anti-virus software between you and us.

Comment: i'm having this problem too

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with IE9.

Go to

Tools/Internet Options

Click the Security Tab

Click the Trusted Sites

Click the Sites button

Paste this URL into the site address box:
https://openid.stackexchange.com/

**NOTE: Do NOT paste in the site URL  you are accessing, that will not help.**

If you are still having problems go back tothe Security Tab, click on "Custom Level" and select "Low" form the pulldown on the bottom and click OK.

Reload the page and you should have access.