# Why does SE want to get my friends list when I try to use Facebook's OpenID?

Tags: support, openid, facebook

I'm sick of Google and want to change my openID, so since I [can't sign up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95541/ie-9-minimum-privacy-and-security-settings-always-get-3rd-party-cookies-disable) for the Stack Exchange OpenID, I figured I'd use the Facebook one.  Then after signing in, it gives me this message before letting me through (note: imgur wouldn't load this):

[imgur broken http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/5981/facebookxl.png](http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/5981/facebookxl.png)

So the question is why does Stack Exchange want my friends list?  I always turn down Facebooks apps that ask for that, do we really need to suck out that much informaation?

*Note: I already know that it's all public in some way, and the rest of the info I've allowed to be public, but there's no reason <strike>to grab</strike> for Facebook to share that list.*

Comment: You're sick of Google and thinking about changing to Facebook? That seems like out of the frying pan and into the fire to me...

Comment: @Cody, yeh, not really any better, my main problems with Google is their non-existent customer support, and not taking input on bugs, which isn't any different on Facebook.  I finally just went with the last option, Yahoo.

Comment: I reached a similar point and went down the OpenID route on my own. Now I get to log into stackexchange (and other OpenID consumers) using a hardware crypto token wherever I am. How awesomely nerdy is that?

Comment: @Flexo very....

Comment: @CodyGray: more like out of the frying pan and into the volcano.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have a feeling this is because Facebook's "basic information" permission *includes* the friends list, among other general things such as name, profile picture, etc. Stack Exchange probably doesn't *access* your friends list at all, but that's just what is shown in the permission request.

Comment: you don't think the info they send Facebook could exclude it?

Comment: I took a look at Facebook's "[Apps on Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#auth)" page, and it seems to me if a program wants to "Access [your] basic information", it automatically has access to all the things on that list.

Comment: I now have new level of disrespect for Facebook, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Lance This also is pretty suspect when you consider if any of your friends sign into third party sites using their facebook account

Answer (score 13):

Just confirming, Kevin & Michael are correct.

There is no way to *not* ask for those permissions when authenticating against Facebook.  The full permission list is [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/), of note is the description of the `read_friendlists` permission.

> Provides access to any friend lists the user created. **All user's
>   friends are provided as part of basic data**, this extended permission
>   grants access to the lists of friends a user has created, and should
>   only be requested if your application utilizes lists of friends.

We do ask for the extra permission `email`, but only for [identification purposes](http://kevinmontrose.com/2011/07/31/your-email-is-practically-your-identity/).  All emails remain opt-in, even if logging in via Facebook.

We also discard the authentication token after login is complete.  You can verify this by checking the last time the `Stack Exchange` [app](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=145044622175352) accessed your information in your Facebook application settings (wherever they've moved that to this week).  It will always correspond with when you last clicked the Facebook button on `/users/login`.

Our app analytics also show the 1 user login -> 1 api call relationship.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your transparency!

Answer (score 10):

"Access my basic information" is the default permission requested by Facebook apps, since (as you said) it's public info. From the [authentication documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/):

> By default, the user is asked to authorize the app to access **basic information** that is available publicly or by default on Facebook. If your app needs more than this basic information to function, you must request specific **permissions** from the user.

I don't think there's a way to not request that permission; Facebook's examples just show adding additional permissions