# Can't login with my Stack Exchange OpenID using Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, login, google-chrome

When I hit login I get "Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled."  Checked the settings, they're not, tried adding an exception, still doesn't work.

Now there's a "continue and login manually" link - click that, enter my info, and get "Not Found" error:

[image]

Any workarounds?

Comment: Norepro for me. Running chrome canary and beta.

Comment: Running 17.0 on Win 7...weird.

Comment: Since you didn't indicate you've seen it (and the tests referred to in the comments), I'm tempted to close as a duplicate of [“Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled” When trying to login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103007/third-party-cookies-appear-to-be-disabled-when-trying-to-login)...

Comment: I didn't see it, just tried everything in the comments..nada :/  Is there another way?  I had the same problem when I initially signed up, somehow I was able to work around it but can't remember how.

Comment: So, that tells me you didn't even try to search this site before posting...? Well, success!

Comment: I did actually - I kept getting threads about Chrome 5 and snarky responses about not using a beta release!

Answer (score 5):

I *think* this was a bug caused by a race condition in storing a session on openid.stackexchange.com.  A fix has been deployed.

Note that clicking that "continue and login manually" link is equivalent to typing "openid.stackexchange.com" into the form on `/users/login`, so it really should never fail.  Thanks for reporting this.